# Is it possible to find a set of 5 integers, such that the 10 sums each have a different last digit?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Full question:

> If we are given 5 integers, there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ different ways to find the sum of 2 of the integers.
>   Is it possible to find a set of 5 integers, such that the 10 sums each have a different last digit?

Am I trying to prove that 5 integers can be found, such that the 10 sums each have a different last digit, or am I being asked to find 5 such integers?

Comment: Should I try this on a few random numbers? @MithleshUpadhyay

Comment: The last digits of each number determine the last digit of their sum thus there are $\binom{10}{5} = 252$ possible groups of $5$ integers.

Comment: @Jared: I think $10^5$ possible groups, since the integers (and most certainly, their unit digits) are not necessarily different.

Comment: @barakmanos Ahh yes, you are correct.  Not to mention it doesn't specify that they cannot be the _same_ integer!

Comment: @Jared: Of course, any group with two identical unit digits is automatically disqualified, because you'll get the same sum when adding each one of them with any one of the other digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $o$ be the number of odd integers in the set. Then you can form $o(5-o)\ne5$ odd sums. Therefore a set of the desired kind does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Idea 1) you have only $10$ possible sums and you *need* ten different results.

Idea 2) Let's look at parity: at least one number is odd and at least one number is even.

- $1$ odd and $4$ even: no, because this gives you only $4$ odd sums, and you need five.
- $2$ are odd and $3$ are even: no, because this gives you $6$ sums with odd result. So at most $4$ sums have even results, while you need at least five of them.
- $3$ are odd and $2$ are even: no, because, again, you have $6$ odd sums.
- $4$ are odd and one is even: no, because you have only $4$ odd sums.

**A precisation:** For the second and third case, one must be careful to what is an odd *result* and what is an *non-ordered pair* $\{ a,b\}$ such that $a+b$ is odd. In total, the number of *non-ordered pairs* at your disposal is $10$. If you have (say) $2$ odd numbers and $3$ even numbers, the number of non-ordered pairs $\{ a,b\}$ such that $a+b$ is odd is exactly $6$. Which leaves *at most* $4$ non-ordered pairs $\{ c,d\}$ with $c+d$ even, hence (at most) four even possible sums. This is where idea $(1)$ comes into play.